# We have a question on Sharepoint regarding search implementation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

For a project I'm looking for any help on Sharepoint Enterprise Search. I am unable to retrieve any results from the search in a Sharepoint list: Search an item textbox. However, I am able to then click through to search the entire site and I will get results back from that. The crawler doesn't give any errors and seems to work. I also checked the settings of the list and made sure that the list is included in the search results. I also checked with Fiddler and see that a post is done and I get a response, but I don't see anything in the JSON result (that's why I don't get any results obviously).
Who can help me out with configuring the Sharepoint search engine?

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: 2010. Could you please reply as soon as if possible. It's an production issue.

Comment: What are you doing with all those hashtags?

Comment: What? Was those hash tags were acting as show stopper for you to answer my query? If possible can you please answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the service account that does not have access to the farm, then the crawler will not be able to crawl the content in the sites.

For example you will use the DOMAIN\SP_admin as you farm admin and use DOMAIN\SP_Search as the account for crawler. In this Case you must add the sp_search as a reader in the entire farm.